# Minecraft Windows 10 Account Vanished?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows

I was able to redeem minecraft windows 10 for free along with Java edition. I haven't played [windows 10 edition] for a while, but now going back to play with a friend who doesn't have java mc, I realized that for whatever reason, there was no sign that I had ever purchased it (even though I already had), and the redeemable code was not where I got it from. How do I get it back? Oddly, or maybe coincidentally, the problem seemed to arise right after the deadline for redeeming the code, in August.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed it. I just needed it reinstall it or something (it said that I already have the game above the purchase button), I thought that it just meant the demo since it never gave me the full version. This time I hit the dropdown menu next to it, and clicked "install on my devices." It asked me to re-enter my Microsoft password, and after it realized that it Minecraft was already installed, I played the game and it finally gave me the full version.

Answer (score 0):

The Minecraft Windows 10 Edition redeem code was removed back in April https://www.polygon.com/2020/4/20/21228331/minecraft-pc-windows-10-free-upgrade-java-rtx-beta
(There is a official Minecraft thread I found a while back but cannot find now)

Comment: Yes, i've seen that article, and I know that the redeem code was removed. I didn't word my question clearly, I meant that I had already redeemed the code and played a few years ago, but now it thinks that I never did and that I have to buy the full version. I thought that maybe the problem had something to do with the code removal thing in April (since I noticed the issue around that time), but I have no idea what the relation could be.